# Select and Insert From two Sql Tables.C#

Tags: c#

my code dosent works. pls correct me.

Example I want to say take 2 values from (COlumn*) Where ....
and 2 values from (COlumn*) Where ....

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
("INSERT INTO temp_rent(parts,size,color,quantities,barcode,name,mobile,code) select 
parts,size,color,quantities,barcode from inventory where barcode = ('" + textBox4.Text + "')
 select name,mobile,code from customermaster where code= '" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
```

Comment: First of all - you should not use query text concatenation since it leads to sql injection and possible values escaping problems. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: `"i want make it smaller and more simple"` - Start by formatting it to be more readable.  That alone goes a *long* way to making code simpler.

Comment: What is the question? You can write a stored procedure and call it instead of this...

Comment: what is the result you want in your query? Can't understand it by simply reading your code... which is not very reader friendly either.

Comment: 1. google sql JOIN
2. Use parametrized queries. What you have is an easy way for a sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

First In visual studio (2015) I have added a data source. Please take into account that different versions of visual studio have different ways to add data source. So in VS2015 click

- project
- add new data source database
- dataset
- configure Your connection to the db
- select tables You will be working with
- name the DataSet (mine is SO_testDataSet)

After finish, You will have a ...DataSet.xsd in the project. Double click on it.

Here You will see the tables You imported from the database. right click on the header of temp_rent, because You want to create a query that will insert into temp_rent at the end.

- Add
- Query
- Here You can use "Use SQL statements" or "Create new stored procedure". I suggest the second one, but for the simplicity use the first now.
- Insert
- Paste the following into the textbox. Check it in the Query Builder if You like.

  ```
  INSERT INTO temp_rent
                   (parts, size, color, quantities, barcode, name, mobile, code)
  SELECT        i.parts, i.size, i.color, i.quantities, i.barcode, cm.name, cm.mobile, cm.code
  FROM            inventory AS i CROSS JOIN
                   customermaster AS cm
  WHERE        (cm.code = @code) AND (i.barcode = @barcode)
  ```
- Name Your Query (mine is InsertQuery)

Finish, save. In the query You can see there is cross join, because inventory and customermasters are not joined by a column. It's a simple Cartesian product. You could use also `FROM inventory, customermaster` or `FROM inventory JOIN customermaster` (because `ON` is optional). We can also see the `@code` and `@barcode` are placeholders for the parametrized query.

In the code You can use the added query like this:

```
SO_testDataSetTableAdapters.temp_rentTableAdapter adapter = new SO_testDataSetTableAdapters.temp_rentTableAdapter();
// I assume that code and barcode are the type of int in the database.
adapter.InsertQuery(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
```

If the textboxes are containing some evil string, the `int.Parse` will throw exception, because the evil string cannot be parsed as int (for the sake of defending from sql injection).